# What is wrong with the codes in this BCP utility running on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

I have created a BCP utility and I have wrapped it in a bat file. I have then created a daily task using Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2012.

The function of the BCP utility is to rename a file called 'myfile.csv' (located in C:) by adding a date stamp to it and updating the file with the result of a SQL query.

The codes currently stand as follows:

```
cd:\Program Files\ Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn
set vardate=%DATE:~4,10%
set varDateWithoutSlashes=%vardate:/=-%
ren C:\myfile.csv myfile_%varDateWithoutSlashes%.csv
bcp "SELECT TOP 100 ReservationStayID,NameTitle,FirstName,LastName,ArrivalDate,DepartureDate FROM MyDatabase.dbo.GuestNameInfo" queryout C:\myfile.csv -t, -c -S [ipaddress] -U sa -P 1234
```

My problem is that when the task runs, it renames the file correctly with a the date stamp but it seems that the SELECT query does not run as the file is empty (except the headers, which have been pre-loaded by the way).

What is wrong with my codes?

I should also add the following:

1. Are the double quotes in the select statement above correct? Or should they be single quotes?
2. Should the ipaddress in my codes above be in square brackets or should I remove them?
3. I have left the "Location" filed 'as is' in the Task Scheduler (please see screenshot below). Should that be filled? If yes, by what?

[image: Task Scheduler Screenshot]

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You are specifying an IP address but no named instance. Run `select @@servername` on your sql server instance and do `-S [ipaddress]\[instancename]` in your bcp command, see what that gives. See [-S](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility#S) option for reference.

Comment: Does it work if you just run the .bat file or are there errors?

Comment: What result you got if you run bcp command in a 'commad Prompt'?

Comment: @TT. Thanks. Problem solved by adding the named instance